# Generate random doubles that follow a specific distribution

Tags: c

So I have the distribution `f(x) = (4-2x)/3`, for `x` in `[0,1]`, and `f(x) = 0` elsewhere.

I now want to generate, say n = 100 random numbers from this distribution. I tried to follow [this](https://www.sanfoundry.com/c-program-generate-random-numbers-using-probability-distribution-function/) example, and this is my own code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//pdf(x) = 1 if x>1
//       = 0 if x<0
//       = 1/3*(4-2x) otherwise

int N = 10;
int var1(int argc, char **argv) {
    int p = 0, i;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        p = (double)(rand() % 100)/100; // Generates 100 numbers in [0,1]
        if (p > 1)
            printf("%d ", 0);  
        else if (p < 0)
            printf("%d ", 0);
        else
            printf("%f ", p * (4-2*0.1)/3);

    }
    printf("...");
    return 0;
}
```

However my output is just zeroes:

```
0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 …
```

I have two questions:

1. What am I missing?
2. In the link I provided, why has he replaced `x` by `0.1`? I just did the same thing but I don't understand why.

Comment: How `p` can ever be greater than `1` or less than `0`?

Comment: Maybe try: `p = (double)(rand() % 100)/100.0`

Comment: @FiddlingBits Shouldn't it work as is?

Comment: @EugeneSh. I don't know. If it performs the division before the cast, no.

Comment: `p` is an int, so attempting to pass in a value between 0 and 1 will cause it to discard anything past the decimal. Since you're casting the result of `rand()` to a `double`, `p` should also be a double. (take care not to accidentally change the type of `i` as well!)

Comment: Yet it is not clear to me how this code is even supposed to achieve the distribution. You are simply scaling the range [0,1)

Comment: You're right, I didn't notice `p` is an `int`.

Comment: @FiddlingBits Casting is higher precedence than division.

Comment: For best range, use `rand()/(double)RAND_MAX`

Comment: The range obtained from `rand()%100.0/100` is `[0, 1[` not `[0, 1]` as in your in-code comment.

Comment: The example you link to uses a *cumulative distribution function* (which it calls a probability distribution function), not a *probability density function*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you're not returning the range of random numbers you think you are:

```
p = (double)(rand() % 100)/100;
```

The right hand size will give you a number in the range ( 0.00, 0.01, 0.02 ... 0.99 ).  But then you assign that value to `p`, which is of type `int`.  The fractional part is truncated, so the assigned value will always be 0.

Change the type of `p` to `double` to store the proper values.  Also, if you want a wider range of random values, use this instead:

```
p = (double)rand() / RAND_MAX;
```

As for this:

```
printf("%f ", p * (4-2*0.1)/3);
```

Compared to the linked code:

```
printf("%f ", p * 0.1 / 360);
```

Their code isn't putting 0.1 in place of `x`.  `p` is the same as `x`, but for some reason they're adding the extra 0.1 factor.

For you to be doing `f(x) = (4-2x)/3`, you need this:

```
printf("%f ", (4-2*p)/3);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your instructive answer! Now atleast I get seemingly correct numbers, however I get the same every time when I build and run the code. Should I not get different every time?

Comment: @Fabled You're not seeding the random number generator.  Call `srand` exactly once in your code to do so.

Comment: Oh yes ofcourse, I actually did this in another script. Thank you very much man! Here is my upvote.

Comment: The question provides a probability density function, f(x). Merely evaluating the function at a point p in [0, 1) will not provide the distribution described by the density function. To generate the requested distribution, one should find the cumulative distribution function F(x) = integral(f(x) from −∞ to x) and then solve F(x) = p.

Comment: Note that the formula in this answer, `(4-2*p)/3)`, produces 4/3 when `p` is zero, which is outside the bounds of the distribution (0 to 1). And, since p never exceeds 1, the formula’s smallest value is 2/3, so it never generates samples in [0, 2/3).

Answer (score 0):

## Preamble

The function in the question, f(*x*) = (4-2*x*)/3 for *x* in [0, 1], is a *probability density function*, not a *cumulative distribution function*. If the distribution were drawn as a curve with unit area between the *x* axis and the curve, the probability density function is the slope of that curve, while the cumulative distribution function is the amount of area under the curve up to a certain *x*.

We can see (4-2*x*)/3 is not a cumulative distribution function because the cumulative distribution must be 1 at the end of the distribution (∞ in general, but 1 here since the function is zero beyond 1, but (4-2*x*)/3 is 2/3 at 1. We can see it is a probability density function because its integral (shown below) is 1 at the end of the distribution.

The [link given in the question](https://www.sanfoundry.com/c-program-generate-random-numbers-using-probability-distribution-function/) uses a cumulative distribution function. In fact, it is a cumulative distribution function for a uniform distribution over [0, 360]. Because of that, solving the necessary equation (see below) is merely a matter of scaling. This is trivial and does not serve as a general example for generating samples for an arbitrary distribution.

## Solution

Given a probability density function, f(*x*), the corresponding cumulative distribution function, F(*x*), is the integral of f from −∞ to *x*. We can use the cumulative distribution function to convert a uniform distribution to the desired distribution.

The integral of (4-2*x*)/3 is (4*x*−*x*<sup>2</sup>)/3 (plus a constant). Since this is zero at *x*=0 and f(*x*) is zero for *x* < 0, F(*x*) is also (4*x*−*x*<sup>2</sup>)/3 in [0, 1].

If we have a sample *p* from a uniform distribution in [0, 1], the point *x* where the amount of the desired distribution at or below *x* equals the amount of the uniform distribution at or below *p* satisfies F(*x*) = *p*.

Thus (4*x*−*x*<sup>2</sup>)/3 = *p*, so *x* = 2 + sqrt(4−3*p*).

Thus, given *p* generated with `p = (double) rand() / RAND_MAX`, we can find the sample for the desired distribution as `2 + sqrt(4-3*p)`.